# Redis sentinel: force switch to another master

Tags: high-availability, redis, testing, redis-sentinel

**Context:**

I have 3 redis nodes, and 3 sentinels. The failover works properly. When I'm taking the master down, another master is elected.

**Need:**

I need a way to test the behavior, to make sure everything works as expected. I wish I could force the sentinels to select a specific redis node to be the master.

I guess I could do that by taking down the two nodes that should not be the master, but I wish I could just issue a command to one of the sentinels to solve my issue.

**tl;dr:**

Can I instruct my sentinels to select a specific redis node as master?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cause a hang on the two Redis-servers you don't want as master and I think (not tested) Sentinel will pick the remaining one. It may take two elections...

Simulating a hang on the Redis servers:

```
redis-cli DEBUG sleep 30
```

or

```
redis-cli DEBUG segfault
```

Then force a fail over:

```
SENTINEL failover
```

---

Perhaps a better approach is to use the priority option.

From https://redis.io/topics/sentinel

#### Slaves priority

> Redis instances have a configuration parameter called slave-priority. This information is exposed by Redis slave instances in their INFO output, and Sentinel uses it in order to pick a slave among the ones that can be used in order to failover a master:
>
> If the slave priority is set to 0, the slave is never promoted to master. Slaves with a lower priority number are preferred by Sentinel.
>
> For example if there is a slave S1 in the same data center of the current master, and another slave S2 in another data center, it is possible to set S1 with a priority of 10 and S2 with a priority of 100, so that if the master fails and both S1 and S2 are available, S1 will be preferred.
>
> For more information about the way slaves are selected, please check the slave selection and priority section of this documentation.

Comment: This solution is nice (especially the segfault, which I didn't know about), but it still requires taking down the current master. I would love to avoid that.